# Accessing Page Template Metadata from a Razor TBB

Tags: tridion

Does anyone know if it's possible to read Page Template Metadata from within a Razor TBB? I'm implementing a design that's been built using the 960 grid system and to keep my CT's reusable I was hoping to be able to do something like:

```
<div class="@Page.Template.Metadata.content_grid">
</div>
```

Unfortunately this throws a null reference exception.

Is what I'm attempting possible or do I need to write a custom TBB to add this information to the package?

Comment: I haven't seen Alex coming around to this side of the Internet, I would probably post about it on his blog: http://www.codedweapon.com/

Comment: Thank for the link - looks like he's planning this as additional functionality for v1.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After heading over to Alex's blog to ask the question, I see that he's already [answered it for someone else](http://www.codedweapon.com/2012/04/razor-mediator-4-tridion-version-1-2-released/):

> Regarding getting Template Metadata out… unfortunately I have not
>   created a wrapper yet for the Template itself, the @Template that is
>   exposed right now is just the
>   Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Template one, which
>   means for now you’ll have to get template fields out the old fashioned
>   way:
>
> @{ Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields.ItemFields
>   templateFields = new
>   ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields.ItemFields(Template.Metadata,
>   Template.MetadataSchema); }
>
> I’ve added this on my To Do list now though, so you’ll be sure to see
>   a convenience wrapper that will allow you to do
>   @Template.MetaData.YourField in version 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this for Component Template Metadata using the following code:

```
@foreach (var cp in ComponentPresentations) {
    @if (cp.Template.Metadata != null && cp.Template.Metadata["position"] != null){
        @Debug(string.Format("The Component Template position is {0}", cp.Template.Metadata["position"].InnerText))
        @if (cp.Template.Metadata["position"].InnerText.ToLower().Equals("main")){                              
            @cp.RenderComponentPresentation()
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore, I think that you should be able to use something similar to the following:

```
@if (Page.Template.Metadata != null && Page.Template.Metadata["content_grid"] != null){
    @Debug(string.Format("The content_grid value is {0}", Page.Template.Metadata["content_grid"].InnerText))
    <div class="@Page.Template.Metadata["content_grid"].InnerText">
    </div>
}
```

Please note the .InnerText and not .Value as the content_grid is returned as xml.  In my code 'position' was just a string. I guess that this may be different if you're using taxonomy.

Thanks,
Jonathan

P.S.  I am using version 1.2 of the Razor Mediator